# Query in a URL to static URL

Tags: php, .htaccess, url

I'm trying to redirect a query string from a URL (?u=user) to a static URL (/user).

So for example:

I currently have it set-up so that if someone types /user in at the end of the URL you'll see the profile page of that user.

What I want is to redirect the http://domain.com/profile.php?u=user to http://domain.com/user

How would I do this?

Thanks, in advance!

Comment: It seems like a pretty trivial extrapolation from the linked answer to what you need. Are you stuck on how to get out the query string (e.g. `$_GET['u']`) to use in building the new URL that you want to redirect to?

Comment: I'm stuck on the part where I redirect the `$_GET['u']` link to the static link.

Comment: I think it's as simple as `header('Location: /'.$_GET['u']);`

Comment: It's not exactly like that. I already have it where it redirects a `/user` link to the user's profile. So right now I want it so that whenever someone enters `profile.php?u=user` the link changes to `/user`. It won't be achieved by using that header code.

Comment: @ChrisDekker That's how it's done. If you want `/profile.php?u=user` to change to `/user`, then you have to perform a redirect.

Comment: How would I make it so that when someone tries to load the page `/profile.php?u=user` it redirects them to `/user`? If I put the `header` function in the page, nothing happens.

Comment: Fixed it using `$url = 'http://' . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
 if (false !== strpos($url,'?u=')) {
  $username = strtolower($username);
     echo "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0; url=http://domain.com/$username\">";
 } else {
     // Do Nothing
 }`